# WFLYEE0043: Component is stopped - what does it mean, why could a component (@Stateless EJB) be stopped?

Tags: java, wildfly-17

I am using Wildfly 17 and I have recieved the folowing Exception two times in the last month:

```
(PriorityExampleScheduler_Worker-1) WFLYEE0043: Component is stopped: org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentIsStoppedException: WFLYEE0043: Component is stopped
at org.jboss.as.ee@17.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.waitForComponentStart(BasicComponent.java:110)
at org.jboss.as.ee@17.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:194)
at org.jboss.as.ee@17.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:185)
at org.jboss.as.ee@17.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:81)
at deployment.heimdi.war//at.home.digest.services.AVeDBService$$$view41.clearWinner(Unknown Source)
at deployment.heimdi.war//at.home.digest.model.dave.OnAveCompletionJob.execute(OnAveCompletionJob.java:36)
at deployment.heimdi.war//org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
at deployment.heimdi.war//org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
```

AVeDBService is marked as a  @Stateless and represents a class accessing the database using JPA.

Wildfly makes and invokes a proxy of this class with the name

```
at.home.digest.services.AVeDBService$$$view41
```

Now: when and why could this compoment be stopped?  Why I recieved this exception only two times in the last month, although the code has been invoked many times?

After I restarted the application, the exception was not thrown anymore, But this does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

This error isn't usually the cause but the result of something else (like app server crash). Monitor app server with tool like VisualVM + create heap dump automatically when app server crash in case of out of memory: -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=

It seems to me that your app server (or your deployed component) was already down when you call this method.

Long time monitor with tool like VisualVM may help you trace the cause of this problem.

Comment: Actually, shortly after recievieng ths exception today I ve got an OutOfMemory error, so, yes, I think you might be rigth. And, thank you for your answer!

Comment: Glad to hear. Did you at the end find out the cause?

Comment: I did not search for the cause, because it was stupid: I just deployet the application, amost done nothing, and then the OutOfMemory came. It was because of java PERM whetevr size, so the "solution" was to increase this paremer in the boot file of WidlFly. Since then, I always restart server after each deployent and it seems to function. The stupid thing is that on my laptop, which has absolutely the same Ubuntu, Java , Wildfly, etc... I never got this error, so it cannot be an application problem, I think